# How can I view a drop cam feed in my own app for iPhone and Android?

Tags: android, iphone

I have a client that wishes to show his drop cam feed in his own app, not the app that drop cam provides. However after calling Dropcam, it seems they offer no such solution and it was advised that I look online for a solution. I have, but it seems the threads are old and there is not a lot of helpful info out there.

I know Dropcam has a beta API but I don't know if I'd need that. They talk of accessing camera info, and other info, which I think I wouldn't really need. I just want to access the feed and isn't that up in the cloud anyways? I wonder if there's a 3rd party video viewer API that can handle this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a little confused so let me help you with that.

When accessing 3rd party content you need to access that information through their services or API. Once you have built a dummy application or understand what information you can access, you can further build an application based off of that info.

Now if your client or friend wants their feeds, you will have to go through the DropCam API and their AUTH system before accessing the feed and they will provide that to you with either a SOAP or REST service response in either XML or JSON.

You parse that information and use the data appropriately in your personal application.

This is a very vague questions so i hope i helped you out.